# Search for entire word containing specific keyword in Notepad++ using regular expressions

Tags: regex, notepad++

I use Notepad++,
i need to search and replace entire word that contain a specific keyword.

Ex: `someting HELP.blablabla.blabla someting`

i would like to search entire text for words that contain the keyword `"HELP"` untill the first space OR the first comma.

In this case: `HELP.blablabla.blabla`

thanks a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to the search panel, check the regex checkbox on the bottom and try: `(HELP)([^ ,]*)`

**Note:** There are a space character after the `^`

This regex means: Search for the entire word HELP `(HELP)` followed by anything that it isn't an space or an comma `[^ ,]` the `^` inside the brackets is a denial

Edit:

You can use just `HELP[^ ,]*` the parenthesis is just to create capturing groups if you need to use the specific groups to replace later. As pointed by @alphabravo

Comment: why two capturing groups?

Comment: Programmers habit. I always use groups if I need to replace then :) Thanks for the note though, I will edit adding this info

Comment: @NikosM. Hi there, I often use some other sites to test regexes like: http://regexr.com/ and https://regex101.com/ which are pretty good. But none of then (nor yours) has specific syntax to Notepad++ it has some particular rules that is why I didn't provid a link with a test demo :) . Thanks though

Comment: @JorgeCampos, sure, i wanted to check the regexs myself and decided to post here, just in case. The tool is open source and one can add other rules if needed. Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

You say search and replace an entire word but if it were that simple then I wonder why a regular search and replace isn't sufficient. So I'm reading between the lines and assuming you want to match on full lines of text.

I think I've used npp enough to get the syntax right. I don't remember any eccentricities that would apply. Is the comma/space optional?

```
^[^, ]*HELP[^, ]*[, ]
```

I'm kinda thinking this one might be good enough:

```
^[^, ]*HELP
```

Comment: **note** you can test regexs online [here](http://foo123.github.io/examples/regex-analyzer/#action=generate&regex=%2F^[^%2C%20]*HELP[^%2C%20]*[%2C%20]%2F) (ps author of this demo tool)